Angular 18 app not running in Safari - "server stopped responding"
I just started a new Angular 18 application.  It's still pretty small.  I've deployed it to Windows server running IIS 10.  When I run it in Chrome or Edge, it works just fine and loads in about 3-5 seconds. When I run it on iPad or iPhone using Safari or Chrome (which is safari with a wrapper), after about 5-10 seconds, I get Safari couldn't open the page because the server stopped responding.
Is there a configuration setting I need or something? This is my 3rd Angular app I've tried and none of them works with Safari.  I can't believe that no Angular apps run on Safari. So, what am I missing?
There are no errors I can see from my devices and nothing is being logged by the server.
Thanks!
I tried running it on both Windows and iOS devices. The Windows devices all work. iOS does not.
